# Output image (jpg) turns red after resizing - Java AWT

Tags: java, awt, jpeg

I have a very simple piece of code that receives a path to an image, reads it and resize it:

```
File inputFile = new File(inputImagePath);
BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(inputFile);

BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics2D = outputImage.createGraphics();
graphics2D.drawImage(inputImage.getScaledInstance(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null);
graphics2D.dispose();

return outputImage;
```

It's working fine for the most files. However, there's one file (that I found, so far) that turns red after resizing. It's a JPG file:

[image: Screenshot]

```
BufferedImage@c4d0fc: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@17476bd transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 1920 height = 1080 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2
```

The other image files that work fine, are also of the type 5.

Why is this happening? The image isn't supposed to have alpha...

Comment: Does using `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` fix things ?

Comment: No, the image then turns kinda green and purple. The other files that were normal, are then rendered as ARG, so blue is stripped off and all of them will be rendered redish. It must be RGB, I'm not getting why is not working with that specific file if it doesn't even have the A layer.

Comment: Not that I believe this is the cause of your issue, but… there is no point in calling inputImage.getScaledInstance, since the call to the [four-int drawImage method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage-java.awt.Image-int-int-int-int-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) will scale the image anyway.

Comment: Well noticed, but I'm calling it to explicitly define the SCALE_SMOOTH algorithm to test if the resulting image has any quality difference

Comment: *"I'm calling it to explicitly define the SCALE_SMOOTH algorithm"* Use a [`RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_INTERPOLATION) of `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC` as a [rendering hint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHint-java.awt.RenderingHints.Key-java.lang.Object-) of the `Graphics2D` instance.

Comment: And a tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, will do. But I think everyone participating on a discussion should be notified by default on their global inbox, shouldn't they?

Comment: Whether they should, or not, is irrelevant. The person that posted the question/answer is notified. If only one person has responded, they're notified. If one person is @ tagged, they're notified. This is a technical site, not a social network.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Then you should focus on answering the question rather than giving me tips on how to tag people.

Comment: *"Then you should focus on answering the question.."* ***Your*** question? There are a lot of people needing help, most of whom ask better questions and appreciate tips on how to use the site. Good luck with it, I'll go help (and give tips to) them.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm pretty sure they won't appreciate your sarcastic and unnecessary comments like "This is a technical site, not a social network". Go on, Mr. Grumpy!

Comment: _"most of whom ask better questions"_ I'm sure you can follow your own tip as well them, because you have questions like this one: _"Why does the first panel disappear?"_  That question of yours is no different from what I posted: the piece of code, the actual result and the expected result. Here's a tip for you: "It’s fine to disagree and express concern, but please be civil. There’s a real human being on the other end of that network connection, however misguided they may appear to be. We’re here to learn from our peers, not yell at each other." It's in the `how-to-answer` page. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do the resizing on the client side, using Javascript. It was much faster and simpler to do. Also, creating decent thumbnails in Java can be surprisingly painful: https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611